# how to make select box for minutes?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How to make a select element for minutes?

```
$this->formSelect('','',null, $myarray_minutes);
```

I tried this but gets wrong minutes https://gist.github.com/668284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would recommend utilizing a plane text box on the zend form side but decorate it with a jquery time selection tool.

- http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/
- http://tobiascohen.com/demos/calendrical/

If you must do it with zend you pas in the options to display with

```
->setMultiOptions($array);
```

Comment: Ok, but if you check my first example of hours, it works!!, but the same concept if i apply for minutes, it doesnt. ex: https://gist.github.com/668284

Comment: Are you certain that is the dump of the minutes array just prior to passing it into the form?  If so I am a bit perplexed myself at the result.

Comment: Here how i solved it, peach of cake.  $this->view->select = array(''=>'') + $fetchAll_rows;

Comment: $this->formSelect('select', '',null, $this->select);  now it print <select name=selct id=selct> < option value= '' > </option> <option...